Removing sharepoint links within formulas using VBA
I have a macro that copies a set of sheets from a source workbook to a new workbook. These sheets contain formulas that reference each other in various ways.
My macro successfully copies over these sheets into the new workbook but the formulas still contain the sharepoint link to the source workbook.
e.g.
Formula copied over as part of sheets:
=SUM('https://companyname.com/teams/Accounts/Shared Documents/Reporting/[sourceworkbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!G:G)+SUM('https://companyname.com/teams/Accounts/Shared Documents/Reporting/[sourceworkbook.xlsx]Sheet2'!G:G)
Formula to be:
=SUM('Sheet1'!G:G)+('Sheet2'!G:G)
There are several differing formulas but this is the basic premise of the problem.
My code that copies the sheets over is this:
    Sub CopySheetsFromWorkbook()
        Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
        Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
        Dim sheetNames As Variant
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim lastSheet As Worksheet
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim sourceWorkbookName As String
    
        ' Set the names of the sheets to copy
        sheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", _
                           "Sheet3")
    
        ' Set the destination workbook (current workbook)
        Set destinationWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
        ' Prompt user to open the source workbook
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
            .Title = "Select the workbook to copy sheets from"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb"
            
            If .Show = -1 Then ' If the user selects a file
                Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
                sourceWorkbookName = sourceWorkbook.Name
            Else
                MsgBox "No file selected. Exiting macro.", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    
        ' Find the sheet before which to paste the copied sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set lastSheet = destinationWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname")
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If lastSheet Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sheet 'Sheetname' not found in the destination workbook.", vbExclamation
            sourceWorkbook.Close False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        ' Loop through the sheet names and copy each one
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sheetNames(i))
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If ws Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Sheet '" & sheetNames(i) & "' not found in the source workbook.", vbExclamation
                sourceWorkbook.Close False
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            ' Create a true copy of the sheet in the destination workbook
            ws.Copy Before:=lastSheet
            
            ' Update formulas to remove references to the source workbook
            With destinationWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name)
                UpdateFormulasToLocal .Cells
            End With
        Next i
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        ' Close the source workbook without saving
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        MsgBox "Sheets copied successfully.", vbInformation
    End Sub

So im assuming its because i am trying to paste rather than use the excel process of right clicking and 'move or copy'. Can this be done?

You should be able to use the ChangeLink functionality to switch the external links to internal ones like this:
Sub MakeSPLinksLocal()
    Dim LinkArray
    Dim i As Long
    LinkArray = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    If Not IsEmpty(LinkArray) Then
        For i = LBound(LinkArray) To UBound(LinkArray)
            If InStr(1, LinkArray(i), "https", vbTextCompare) Then ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink LinkArray(i), ActiveWorkbook.FullName, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

